# Except command doesn't work in SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum, except

I am trying to make an except in SQL but it doesnt exclude the data even though they are identical.

```
SELECT A.payment_id,
                            SUM(A.importe_trx) monto_total
FROM  [dbo].[ABONOS] A
WHERE payment_id = '980190391415704'
GROUP BY A.payment_id

SELECT B.payment_id payment_id,
                            SUM(B.precio_venta) monto_total
FROM [dbo].[SALES_VISANET_USD] B
WHERE payment_id = '980190391415704'
GROUP BY B.payment_id
```

I used that query to get the data and it's the same, but it doesn't exclude it with the `EXCEPT` command in the middle

```
SELECT A.payment_id,
                            SUM(A.importe_trx) monto_total
FROM  [dbo].[ABONOS] A
WHERE payment_id = '980190391415704'
GROUP BY A.payment_id

EXCEPT

SELECT B.payment_id payment_id,
                            SUM(B.precio_venta) monto_total
FROM [dbo].[SALES_VISANET_USD] B
WHERE payment_id = '980190391415704'
GROUP BY B.payment_id
```

I use "sum" because in one of the tables it has different amounts with the same payment_id, but when adding and grouping them they give the same amount and the same data as the other table.

Comment: You'll need to include your table definitions and sample data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I mean that the "except" function does not make the exception. "importe_trx" and "precio_venta" stores the same data (float) that are the prices. The reason for the "sum" is because I am crossing some information, so I am telling you that if this code with this amount from table "A" is also in table "B", it will exclude it. But apparently there is something preventing me from excluding him.

Comment: -------------------------------------
SELECT payment_id,precio_venta
FROM [dbo].[SALES_VISANET_USD]
WHERE payment_id = '980190391415704'
--------------------------------------
SELECT payment_id,importe_trx
FROM [dbo].[ABONOS]
WHERE payment_id = '980190391415704'
--------------------------------------
TABLE SALES_VISANET_USD
payment_id precio_venta
980190391415704 18.42
980190391415704 24.56

------------------------------------
TABLE ABONOS
payment_id importe_trx
980190391415704 42.98

Comment: It's very important to keep in mind that floating point values are approximate values, even if they look identical to you. You must make sure the columns have precision (i.e. using a DECIMAL type) before comparing them.

Comment: @LuisC. please edit your question instead of adding a query to the comments

Answer (score 1):

From you comment:

> "importe_trx" and "precio_venta" stores the same data (float) that are the prices

That means you are using float data type to store these numerical values.
Problem with the float data type is that it always store rounded values, it can not precisely represent decimal values. Each values is saved as `(0 or 1)*1/2+(0 or 1)*1/4+(0 or 1)*1/8+...`, so 18.42 + 24.56 can be 42.98000000001 in float terms. SSMS will round these numbers, so you will not see the difference.

To fix this problem you should use decimal data type. Never use floats in any accounting data.